# Можно ли узнать источник диска, который был смонтирован?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mount

Допустим, есть внешний диск, на этом внешнем диске есть ISO образ.
Если я смонтирую ISO, то появится новый виртуальный диск с содержимым этого образа.

Я могу как-нибудь проанализировав виртуальный диск узнать с какого реального устройства смонтирован образ?

Comment: Разработчики DRM тоже очень хотели это знать... :)

Answer (score 4):

Нет, без добровольной помощи драйвера, с помощью которого был смонтирован образ, этого выяснить нельзя. А драйверы программ для монтирования `ISO`, как правило такую информацию не предоставляют и прикидываются настоящими устройствами. Это нужно не только для обхода всяческих систем защиты контента, но и для обхода ограничений самой самой `ОС`, которые иногда ощутимо мешают вполне легальным действиям. Более того, начиная с `Win8`, `Microsoft` предоставляет родные средства для монтирования образов, с чего бы это?

`ISO` - это не полная бинарная копия диска, чем в свое время активно пользовались при защите игр, но тот же `DaemonTools` прекрасно умеет работать и с полными бинарными образами, а `NERO` умеет такие образы создавать. И это не единственные в своем роде программы, просто пример.

Так что если вы думаете как защититься от копирования вашего контента (а иначе зачем еще знать какой именно образ смонтирован, если сами монтировали, то и так знаете), привязка к диску вам не поможет, ее научились успешно обходить более 10 лет назад, а то и раньше, и эффективных способов борьбы против этого нет, ищите другие решения.